# Regular expression to validate US phone numbers using Formik and Yup

Tags: python, reactjs, django, formik

I'm trying to validate us phone numbers inside my formik form using yep. I found some information on regex here on stackoverflow but it doesn't seem to be working. I basically need to be able to allow brackets, dashes and spaces aswell as the country code. The backend converts everything into something like this: (123) 123-1234

This is what i tried:

```
                    validationSchema={Yup.object({
                        AdministratorCell: Yup.string()
                            .matches(/([0-9]{3})[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}/, {
                                message: "Invalid phone number",
                                excludeEmptyString: false,
                            })
                    })}
```

I'm using https://github.com/google/libphonenumber in the backend for backend validation of those phone numbers which is why i need frontend validation to properly work or the form won't submit in some cases where users forget a number or format the number in a certain way.
My issue is with what i tried so far is that i can only add the phone number with a certain formatting or it will not submit to the backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex it can meet your requirements

```
 /^((\(\d{3}\) ?)|(\d{3}-))?\d{3}-\d{4}$/
```

It would look something like that:

```
validationSchema={Yup.object({
     AdministratorCell: Yup.string()
        .matches(/^((\(\d{3}\) ?)|(\d{3}-))?\d{3}-\d{4}$/, {
           message: "Invalid phone number",
           excludeEmptyString: false,
     })
})}
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing I see is that the area code is required. Sometimes people don't specify that if in some case it's assumed to be local. You'll need a ? after the ) to make it optional.

Parentheses are used for grouping in regular expressions so you don't want to use them as literals. You'll want to escape them if you don't want them to used to group the area code.

There's no separator between your area code and the rest of the number.

You may want to replace the - separator with [- .]+ or similar, in case the user uses a different separator, or if they do something like 111 - 111 - 1111.

Some examples of what's not working might be helpful.