# I want to create A formik FieldArray component for Listing of phone numbers with - & + buttons

Tags: formik

This is how i created a FieldArray

[image]

And this is my intialValues object

[image]

how to validate it?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code or other text. Copy the original text to your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular expression to validate US phone numbers using Formik and Yup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71999647/regular-expression-to-validate-us-phone-numbers-using-formik-and-yup)